# Initialization from incompatible pointer type (pointer to a function)

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I'm completely stuck at this point. I have the following code in 3 files:

file
mixer_oss.c

```
#include "mixer.h"

static char *devices[] = SOUND_DEVICE_NAMES;

static char **oss_get_device(void)
{
    int i, o, devs, res;
    char **result;

    if ((ioctl(fd, SOUND_MIXER_READ_RECMASK, &devs)) == -1) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        result = malloc(sizeof(char*)*SOUND_MIXER_NRDEVICES);
        o = 0;
        for (i=0; i < SOUND_MIXER_NRDEVICES; i++) {
                res = (devs >> i)%2;
                if (res) {
                    result[o] = malloc(strlen(devices[i])+1);
                    sprintf(result[o], "%s", devices[i]); 
                    o++;
                }
                result[o] = NULL;   
            }
    }

    return result;
}

struct mixer oss_mixer = {
    .get_device = oss_get_device,
};
```

file
mixer.h

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

struct mixer
{
    char (* get_device) (void);
};

#pragma weak oss_mixer
extern struct mixer oss_mixer;


#ifdef __cplusplus
};
#endif
```

file
mixer.c

```
#include "mixer.h"

static char null_get_device(void)
{
}

static struct mixer *mixers[] = {
    &oss_mixer,
    &null_mixer
};
```

Now, when I compile the code, this is what I get

```
mixer-oss.c: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
.get_device = oss_get_device,
^

warning: (near initialization for ‘oss_mixer.get_device’) [enabled by default]
```

Could you please help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a debugger?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`char (* get_device) (void);` declares a pointer to a function that takes no argument and returns a `char`.

`static char **oss_get_device(void)` is a function that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to pointer to `char`.

Your pointer to a function should be declared like this:

```
char ** (*get_device)(void);
```

Now it is compatible with `oss_get_device`.